# How to access the variable in angular js to a route

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have the code in html with Angular js:

```
 <li ng-repeat="item in newsItems | filter:q">
 {{item.posts}}</br>
 by: {{item.pseudoname}} 
       <form name="edit" href="@routes.Application.deleteTask({{item.posts}})" method="get">
           <input type="submit" value="Delete">
       </form>
 </li>
```

where item is an object that has. item.posts, item.pseudoname and item.id. Whenever i run the code item.posts and item.pseudoname displays in the browser but the item.posts inside the form is not found. M

My question is how can use item.posts in routes.Application.deleteTask. because this route need item.posts?

Comment: what is @routes.Application.deleteTask ?

Comment: it is route. i need the variable item.posts in it. deleteTask is working whenever i try to put a sample String. example: @routes.Application.deleteTask("string")

Comment: Can you show us exactly what you're getting from the server? i.e. can you console.log($scope.newItems) and show us what you've got?
What I'm trying to understand, and this might help others figuring out the problem, is if your posts property is actually being filled in with data.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I already found the mistake. the @ sign refers to the code for scala so that's why it didn't read{{item.posts}}. I forgot to mention that the html file is in play scala framework. sorry for the mistake thank you.